# I Can't Edit my files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

For some unknown reason, I can't edit files in Android Studio. This include both java and xml files and other files ,
I can't edit nothing - cut files , or delete , write , nothing worked..
Files are not locked as Read-Only. I checked.
Restarting Android Studio did not resolve my problem. 
Please Help me ! Thanks

Comment: What error does the editor show?  Is the editor running as the same user as the user who owns the files?  Can you create and save new files?  What is the error then?

Comment: no it's not running same user that file

Comment: it's another person file , it's then impossible to edit files ?

Comment: If a file belongs to user "foo" and the write permission is not set to ALL users, then user "bar" can not edit the file.  If you have read access, you can copy the files to your own folder and edit the copies.  If you have root / admin access you can also change the owner but that might break things unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I Have that game apk files on my pc if if open them with notepad++ shows weird symbols and there i can edit all what i want...

Comment: but when i open that file in android studio then its on normal format but cant edit

Comment: looks like best way is copy all files then

Comment: and if i extract my apk to another file then i can open and edit files  in android studio , but again weird symbols shows

Comment: You're trying to edit someone else's compiled and packaged android application that you downloaded?  You do not have the source code for it?

Comment: yes it's someone else's compiled application that i downloaded , have some ideas ? how i can edit it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: where to find source code

Answer (score 1):

This Can happen when you loose the focus of your Code View. you can keep focus by having a click on Scroll bar (right side) in the Android Studio.

This problem was in Android Studio version 1.2.2, So haven't experienced recently.
please Update Android Studio.